# DFA that accepts word and its reverse

Tags: finite-automata

The problem is as follows: design DFA over an alphabet {a,b}, that accepts a language: L = {$xwx^R$ | $x \in \{a,b\}^+, w \in \{a,b\}^+$}

I have no idea how to remember the first word to be able to detect a reverse of it. I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Okay, I found the solution. We have to assume that $w \in \{a,b\}$ so we have to only check if first and the last letter is the same.

Comment: @Apass.Jack While some reputation is required to close questions, you can always try to [flag your own post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176386/flag-and-close-my-own-question), requesting closure so that it ends up in the close votes queue. (While flagging everywhere requires 15 rep, flagging on (comments on) your own post can be done by everyone)